# how to set transparent text color of JTextField

Tags: java

I want to set the transparent text color of JTextField, means the color of the text on JTextField should be same as that of JFrame on which JTextField is added. Please tell how can I do this?

Comment: Okay, that doesn't seem to make sense, then wouldn't you not be able to read the text?  Can you sight an example?

Answer (score 1):

This is possibly a massive overkill, but as I understand the question, essentially, what this does is makes the text "transparent" or appear "cut out" of the text field...

[image]

```
public class CutoutTextField extends JTextField {

    public CutoutTextField() {
        init();
    }

    public CutoutTextField(String text) {
        super(text);
        init();
    }

    public CutoutTextField(int columns) {
        super(columns);
        init();
    }

    public CutoutTextField(String text, int columns) {
        super(text, columns);
        init();
    }

    public CutoutTextField(Document doc, String text, int columns) {
        super(doc, text, columns);
        init();
    }

    protected void init() {
        setOpaque(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        TextUI ui = getUI();

        // This is JUST the text
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D ig = img.createGraphics();
        applyQualityRenderingHints(ig);
        ui.paint(ig, this);
        ig.dispose();

        // This is the background of the field...
        BufferedImage bg = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        ig = bg.createGraphics();
        applyQualityRenderingHints(ig);
        ig.setColor(getBackground());
        ig.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        ig.dispose();

        BufferedImage masked = ImageUtilities.applyMask(img, bg, AlphaComposite.XOR);
        int y = (getHeight() - masked.getHeight()) / 2;
        g.drawImage(masked, 0, y, this);
    }

    public BufferedImage applyMask(BufferedImage sourceImage, BufferedImage maskImage, int method) {

        BufferedImage maskedImage = null;
        if (sourceImage != null) {

            int width = maskImage.getWidth(null);
            int height = maskImage.getHeight(null);

            maskedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D mg = maskedImage.createGraphics();
            applyQualityRenderingHints(mg);

            int x = (width - sourceImage.getWidth(null)) / 2;
            int y = (height - sourceImage.getHeight(null)) / 2;

            mg.drawImage(sourceImage, x, y, null);
            mg.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(method));

            mg.drawImage(maskImage, 0, 0, null);

            mg.dispose();

        }

        return maskedImage;

    }

    public void applyQualityRenderingHints(Graphics2D g2d) {

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);

    }

}
```

Understand, this is a massive hack!

What this basically does, is paints the text from field to a `BufferedImage`, it then generates a separate `BufferedImage` filled with the background color of the field and then `XOR`'s the two images together, effectively cutting the text out of the background.  It then simply paints the resulting `BufferedImage`.

Some will note that I've not called `super.paintComponent`, this is done deliberately as I don't want the field to paint the background AND text but want to take control over the process.

It's possible, because the field is transparent, that I could call `super.paintComponent`, but I'd be painting to one of the `BufferedImage`s any way...